# How can I improve the sharpness of my Sigma 50mm 1.4 DG HSM lens?

Tags: lens, sharpness

I've had it for a while but haven't used it much because it is not sharp. Suggestions? Can it be sent off and is that expensive?

Comment: Please post some example photos. It's possible that the problem is not with the lens.

Comment: Have you tried doing a lens calibration on your camera ?

Comment: Applicable: ["This lens is soft" and other myths](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/12/this-lens-is-soft-and-other-myths/)

Comment: As well as: [Notes on Lens and Camera Variation](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/10/notes-on-lens-and-camera-variation/)

Comment: [“This Lens Is Soft” and Other Facts](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2010/03/this-lens-is-soft-and-other-facts/)

Comment: Probably it is a good idea to post a photo taken with this lens. "Not sharp" can mean different things. Focus, dirt, resolution, artifacts...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 2 things:

1) Stopping down the aperture, try clicking pics at f/8 or f/11. This negates the use of a fast aperture lens such as yours, but it will point to the next step. By stopping down, we increase the DOF, and thus some focusing errors can be hidden.

2) Performing Micro-focus adjustment. Since you have not mentioned which brand camera you are using, this may or may not be available directly in camera. This should be performed by a knowledgeable camera technician, if it is not available in camera menus.

A third and very distant possibility is a lens focus mechanism failure.